# JavaScript split array in half juxtapose the first half with second half

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flatten

What is the method to evenly split an array into two.  Then, position the second half underneath the first all for the purpose of comparing whether or not a new final array should receive a zero or one in the slots.

`var master_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38];`

`var first_half = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];`

`var second_half = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38];`

`var final_usable_array_reduced = [];`

So, given a form with 38 check boxes, if the 5th, 19th, 37th, and 38th check boxes were checked, the `final_usable_array_reduced` would be

`final_usable_array_reduced = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];`

`final_usable_array_reduced[4] = **represents the 5th <strong>or</strong> 24th box being checked**`

`final_usable_array_reduced[18] = **represents the 19th <strong>or</strong> 38th boxes being checked**`

Comment: So, the reduced array must have an "or" relationship?, if in the same position of array one "or" two has 1, the reduced one must be 1?

Comment: @Macarthurval You are correct, it is an "or" relationship.  It's like you're flattening/reducing the array from 38 to 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement this with a simple `for` loop over half the `master_array`, `or`ing the values in the bottom half of the array with those in the top half:

```js
var master_array = new Array(38).fill(0);
master_array[4] = 1;
master_array[18] = 1;
master_array[36] = 1;
master_array[37] = 1;

let len = master_array.length / 2;
final_usable_array_reduced = new Array(len);
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  final_usable_array_reduced[i] = master_array[i] | master_array[i + len];
}
console.log(final_usable_array_reduced);
```

Comment: thanks is that new Array stuff and the single | operator ES 5.1 and lower?  Can I just replace the let with `var`?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon yes, you can replace `let` with `var`. And `new Array(len)` and the bitwise or operator `|` have been around since day 1.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Other than the `fill` which I use to initialise `master_array` (but presumably you don't need), this code runs fine on IE11.

Comment: +1 for the bitwise insight.  I took inspiration from Twisty's answered as well with that `math.floor` syntax.  But I would say though, I know we're in 2020, but don't forget that someone out there still uses IE 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```js
var array = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0];
var firstHalf = array.slice(0,array.length/2);
var secondHalf = array.slice(array.length/2);
var result = firstHalf.map(function(e,i){
    return e || secondHalf[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

What I'm doing here is spliting the array into two halfs with `slice` (considering that the array elements are even, of course), and after that I map the first one returning 1 (or true, is the same) if `firstArray[i]` or `secondArray[1]` is 1.

Comment: This is good. May you kindly use ES 5.1 or lower syntax. Not used to the new stuff and going for mac browser support.

Comment: I just ran it at mac Safari without a problem!, but I'm goin to rewrite it a little more clear.

Comment: Sorry to on cell phone. Meant max browser compatible (IE does not support a lot of the ES6 shorthand)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function addChecks(count, tObj, cont) {
    var i;
    if (cont == undefined) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i = parseInt($("input:last").val()) - 1;
      count = i + count;
    }
    for (i; i <= count; i++) {
      $("<input>", {
        type: "checkbox",
        value: (i + 1),
        title: (i + 1)
      }).appendTo(tObj);
    }
  }

  function checksToArray() {
    var arr = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).prop("checked"));
    });
    return arr;
  }

  function compHalfArr(a) {
    var arr = [];
    var h = Math.floor(a.length / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i <= h; i++) {
      arr.push(a[i] || a[(i + h)]);
    }
    return arr;
  }

  addChecks(14, $(".section-1"));
  addChecks(14, $(".section-2"), true);

  $("button").click(function() {
    var allChecks = checksToArray();
    var compChecks = compHalfArr(allChecks);
    $(".results").html("<span>" + compChecks.join("</span><span>") + "</span>").find("span:last").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.checks input {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.results span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checks section-1"></div>
<div class="checks section-2"></div>
<button>Check</button>
<div class="results"></div>
```

You can do a loop using a halfway marker.